# I am trying to execute the python script on remote server using SSH but fails

Tags: bash

script is like below

```
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.load_host_keys('/user/hokale')         
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
my_key = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file('/user/hokale')
client.connect(hostname=host, username=user, password=password,pkey=my_key)
```

The remote script present `@ locaton /user/hokale`. the load_host_keys api or `paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file` fails saying

```
in load
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:/user/hokale
```

Please suggest the solution

Comment: And /user/hokale exists on the remote server?

Answer (score 0):

I infer from your question that /user/hokale is a directory as you say "a remote script present at /user/hokale".

`load_host_keys` takes a filename as an argument, not a directory. If your host keys file is for example /user/hokale/foo/known_hosts, you need to point to that file instead of a directory.

And remember, Paramiko host keys file will probably look different than your ssh known hosts file. A typical mistake is to point to a ssh known_hosts file and expect it to work.